# What is the bookle-5.local user account on the MAMP Pro MySQL load?

Tags: mysql, mamp-pro

I have an install of MAMP Pro 5. The MAMP Pro MySQL has a user account named bookle-5.local. Is this normal? Do you know what it is for?

Comment: Actually, it's a hostname (at least on my install).  I just noticed it as well.  I would love an answer to this.